# Segmentation Fault when trying to use EF Core 6 on Debian

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, debian, sql-server-2019

I am trying to deploy my EF Core web api project to a Debian 9 VPS

I have gotten the web api running smoothly, however when trying to use EF it exits (Segmentation Fault)

I am running a SQL Express server (2019) on the Debian 9 vps, which functions correctly (SSMS working correctly)

[image: The segmentation fault]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to update tooling and EF Core packages, 6.0.0.rc.2 is outdated version.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for your reply, i have updated the packages. sadly with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update package `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to version 5 or above.